# state not getting checked correctly inside click handler function in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am building a online multiplayer tic-tac-toe game with firebase and next-js. In that game, I want to check for turns of players i.e if next turn is of "O" then "X" should not be able to change any tile and apposite. Fist fixed move is always "X" in the game and I have created a state variable called **isNextO**

```
   const [isNextO, setIsNextO] = useState("yes");
```

which is "yes" initially but when "O" plays its move it makes state change to "no" as follows

```
   var isTurn = isNextO === "yes" ? "no" : "yes";
   setIsNextO(isTurn);
```

but when I check the isNextO inside an if statement, it always evaluates to true

```
   if (isNextO === "yes") {
      console.log("Next is O");
      if (host == 1) {
        console.log("Host is playing");
        return;
      } else if (guest == 1) {
        var isTurn = isNextO === "yes" ? "no" : "yes";
        setIsNextO(isTurn);
        console.log(`Is Next O: ${isTurn} `);
      }
    }
```

even if the value of isNextO is "no" the above main if statement evaluates to true and as a result my host does not get to play a single move. There are some database (realtime database) operations in the **useEffect**. Following is the full code of the file. Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Square from "./Square";
import styles from "../styles/Game.module.css";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";
const database = firebase.database();

const Board = ({ code, host, getUsers, guest }) => {
  const reference = database.ref(`/game/${code}`);
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState("");
  const [isNextO, setIsNextO] = useState("yes");
  const sq = squares;
  const handleClick = (i) => {
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    if (isNextO === "yes") {
      console.log("Next is O");
      if (host == 1) {
        console.log("Host is playing");
        return;
      } else if (guest == 1) {
        var isTurn = isNextO === "yes" ? "no" : "yes";
        setIsNextO(isTurn);
        console.log(`Is Next O: ${isTurn} `);
      }
    }
    var move = "";
    if (host == 1) {
      move = "X";
    } else if (guest == 1) {
      move = "O";
    }
    // setisNextO(!isNextO);
    // reference
    //   .once("value")
    //   .then((snapshot) => {
    //     const fetchedData = snapshot.val();
    //     const newMovesFetched = fetchedData.moves;
    //     if (host === true) console.log("this is X");
    //     else console.log("this is O");
    //     console.log(`Move: ${move}`);
    //     newMovesFetched.push({
    //       move,
    //       index: i,
    //     });
    //     reference
    //       .update({
    //         moves: newMovesFetched,
    //       })
    //       .then((res) => {
    //         setisNextO(!isNextO);
    //       })
    //       .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    //   })
    //   .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };

  if (!winner) {
    const winn = calculateWinner(squares);
    if (winn) {
      reference
        .update({
          winner: winn,
        })
        .then(() => {
          setWinner(calculateWinner(squares));
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const change = database.ref(`/game/${code}`).on("value", (snap) => {
      const data = snap.val();
      if (data.guest && data.host) {
        const user = {
          guest: data.guest,
          host: data.host,
          winner: data.winner,
        };
        getUsers(user);
      }
      const squares = sq.slice();
      const moves = data.moves;
      for (let i = 0; i < data.moves.length; i++) {
        const index = moves[i].index;
        const move = moves[i].move;
        squares[index] = move;
        console.log(moves[i]);
      }
      setSquares(squares);
    });
    return () => database.ref(`/game/${code}`).off("value", change);
  }, []);

  const renderSquare = (i) => {
    return <Square value={squares[i]} onClick={() => handleClick(i)} />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      {winner ? (
        <h1>{winner}</h1>
      ) : (
        <div className={styles.board}>
          {renderSquare(0)}
          {renderSquare(1)}
          {renderSquare(2)}
          {renderSquare(3)}
          {renderSquare(4)}
          {renderSquare(5)}
          {renderSquare(6)}
          {renderSquare(7)}
          {renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

export default Board;
```

**Note**: The commented part is for database operations based on moves played by players and is commented so as to avoid extensive read-writes while testing the code.

Comment: `setState` only takes effect on the next render https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-props-and-state

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova can you suggest any solution? The console log after ```setIsNextO``` shows state 
correctly

Comment: You can use `isTurn` instead of `isNextO` inside the handler (after you called  `setIsNextO(isTurn);` you know that  `isNextO` will have value of  `isTurn` eventually)

Comment: Also React has an official tutorial for that same game, you might want to have a look https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: The game in that tutorial is to played locally but I am trying to build it with firebase so that two players can play online

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova can you show me how to implement the solution you suggested with that click handler function?

Comment: What are the values for `host` and `guest`? How are they suppose to change?

Comment: I have two screens **createGame** which sends the prop host as 1 and the prop guest as 0 and  **joinGame** which sends the host and guest props apposite that of createGame to the current Board component

Comment: I think your problem is not so much state as too many variables. If `host` is 1, can `guest` be anything but 0? Of no, why do you need `guest` at all? Similarly `isNextO` should really be a boolean, rather than string

Comment: by setting  **isNexto** as boolean I got same ambiguities as now thats why I changed it to a string to see if it works and same happens with ```host``` and ```guest``` as well. By doing a bit of trial and error, I chose to set host 1 and guest 0. I am not that experienced in react..